# Не понимаю что я делаю не так

Tags: java

Задача: Программа вводит с клавиатуры пару (число и строку) и выводит их на экран.

Новая задача: Программа вводит с клавиатуры пары (число и строку), сохраняет их в HashMap.
Пустая строка - конец ввода данных.
Числа могут повторяться. Строки всегда уникальны.  Введенные данные не должны потеряться!

Затем программа выводит содержание HashMap на экран. Каждую пару с новой строки.

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    /* 
    Функциональности маловато!
    */

    public class Solution {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            HashMap <String, Integer> list = new HashMap <String, Integer> ();
            while (true) {
                String s = reader.readLine();
                if (s.isEmpty()) {
                    break;
                }
                try {
                    Integer id = Integer.parseInt(s);
                    String name = reader.readLine();
                    if (name.isEmpty()) {
                        break;
                    }

                    list.put(name, id);
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> pair : list.entrySet()) {
                        System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " " + pair.getValue());
                    }
                    break;
                }

            }

            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> pair : list.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " " + pair.getValue());
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: Где ошибка? Почему вопрос возникает?

Comment: Валидатор пишет: Если вместо числа была введена пустая строка, то программа должна вывести содержимое HashMap согласно условию.

Comment: для таких заданий неплохо бы приводить корректный  ввод и вывод в тексте вопроса

Comment: Вроде всё работает корректно у вас.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно вас понял, то вы должны поправить

```
if (s.isEmpty()) {
    break;
}
```

на

```
if (s.isEmpty()) {
    return list;
}
```

**P.S**
Тут многое зависит от того, что у вас за валидатор. Как я понял, это какая-то задачка с сайта или из java-rush. 
В проверке валидатора может как мой первый ответ пройти, так и эта правка

Переместите ваш **for-цикл** в отдельный метод

```
   private void showMap(HashMap<String, Integer> list){
     if(!map.isEmpty()){
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> pair : list.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " " + pair.getValue());
        }
     }
   }
```

и тогда весь ваш класс будет выглядеть примерно так

```
 public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        HashMap <String, Integer> list = new HashMap <String, Integer> ();
        while (true) {
            String s = reader.readLine();
            if (s.isEmpty()) {
                showMap(list);
            }
            try {
                Integer id = Integer.parseInt(s);
                String name = reader.readLine();
                if (name.isEmpty()) {
                    break;
                }

                list.put(name, id);
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                showMap(list);
                break;
            }
            showMap(list);
        }



   private void showMap(HashMap<String, Integer> list){
        if(!map.isEmpty()){
            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> pair : list.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " " + pair.getValue());
            }
        }else {
           return null;
        }
   }
```

И тут надо смотреть, что от вас хочет валидатор.

Comment: как я это реализую, если это не метод и нет типа возвращаемого объекта?

Comment: я же написал **поправить**, а не **дописать**. А именно в куске `while (true) {
                String s = reader.readLine();
                if (s.isEmpty()) {
                    break;
                }
                try {` Наверное, это 13 строка, примерно